# Why are files auto-converted to JPEG when transfer from Nikon D7200 to a PC?

Tags: nikon, raw, software

I clicked all my pictures in RAW-only format. But when I transferred to my PC all my files are auto converted to JPEG. Please note I selected only Raw in my camera settings, not Raw + Jpeg.

For photo transfer I'm using the WMU app on my iPhone. I also noticed while transfer I have .NEF files

Is this happening with anyone else?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WMU app seems oriented around sharing photos, for which RAW isn't an appropriate option.

Page 20 of the [manual](http://nikonimglib.com/ManDL/WMAU-ios/) says "NEF (RAW) images are converted to JPEG format"

Additionally: "if the images were recorded using an NEF(RAW) + JPEG option, only the JPEG copy will be downloaded."

If you want to work with RAW files on your PC, you'll need to use a card reader or cable and file transfer software.